# How does Spark web UI calculate duration for completed jobs?

Tags: apache-spark

So transformations in Spark are lazy which means that they are not executed until an action has been executed.

Does the same concept apply to the timing that is done by Spark? For instance, I have a program which reads in a bunch of text files, runs some algorithms on them and finally runs a `foreach` on the RDD which prints out some data.

When I inspect "Completed Jobs" in the Spark UI, there is only one job which is the `foreach`. This job took 1.5 min and the total uptime was 1.6 min. Does this 1.5 min include the time it took to read and create the initial RDD, run the algorithms on the RDD and finally run whatever was in the `foreach` clause (because the `map`, `filter` and other transformations I ran on the RDD are lazy)? Or does this 1.5 min only show the time it took for whatever code was in the `foreach` clause?

Side question: Is it possible to "mark" some functions to be timed, for instance if I have a `RDD.map` that I would like to know the time of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time includes time to read data and apply all transformations necessary to complete the action.

If there are some transformations defined which is not necessary to complete the action then those transformation will not be ran by spark.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this makes sense. However, it seems hard to find out the time it took to for example read the data and to process it.